How to Use Feign Client Https Request Instead Of Http
I started using https instead of http in my microservice architecture application. When a request is made with Feign Client, it uses http instead of https.
I created the following class which configures ssl for Feign but it is not working.
@Bean
    public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() throws Exception {
        return Feign.builder()
                .retryer(Retryer.NEVER_RETRY)
                .client(feignClient());
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory createSSLContext() throws Exception {
        String trustStorePath = "/home/kaan/NetBeansProjects/SociMedia/BlockService/src/main/resources/truststore.jks";
        String keyStorePath = "/home/kaan/NetBeansProjects/SociMedia/BlockService/src/main/resources/keystore.jks";
        String pass = "pass";
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); 
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStorePath)), pass.toCharArray());

        SSLContext context = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile(trustStorePath), pass.toCharArray())
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, pass.toCharArray())
                .build();
        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public Client feignClient() throws Exception {
        return new Client.Default(createSSLContext(), org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    }


    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> converters) {
        return new ResponseEntityDecoder(new SpringDecoder(converters));
    }


    @Bean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        return new SpringFormEncoder();
    }

I use this class every feign client interface as configuration parameter.
When I access the https://192.168.1.59:9090/v1/user/get?id=2 endpoint, I get the following error:
BlockService executing GET http://BlockService/v1/block/blocked?userId1=25&userId2=2
feign.RetryableException: BlockService executing GET http://BlockService/v1/block/blocked?userId1=25&userId2=2
